# Java android intent service

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I write a intent service to send image to server. I start a service in one activity (in onResume) in onDestroy I stop service. This should works just like this : I take a photo and I have a ArrayList with photo path . And In service I send a photo. I want to send a one photo and when is sending I wait and send another. When I capture photo , confirm (I have 2 photo to send ) and go back to intent (and start service) I see a black screeen.

Service :

```
public class Sendrer extends Service {

    public static boolean running = false;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private SendPhotoTask asyncSender;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("tworzenie serwisu ", "tworzenie");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("Dziełanie serwisu ", "Dziełanie");

        while (!  ConfirmDetailsPGOActivity.myList.isEmpty()) {
            if(!running) {
                asyncSender = new SendPhotoTask();
                asyncSender.execute();
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (running) {
            timer.cancel();
            asyncSender.cancel(true);
            running = false;
        }
//        asyncSender.cancel(true);
        Log.e("service " , "nie działa");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    class SendPhotoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            running = true;
            InputStream responseInputStream = null;
            try {
                responseInputStream = HttpConnectionsUtil.sendPhotoRequest(getApplicationContext(), true,   ConfirmDetailsPGOActivity.myList.get(0));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("Wysyłanie zdjęcia ", convertStreamToString(responseInputStream));
            return convertStreamToString(responseInputStream);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            ConfirmDetailsPGOActivity.myList.remove(0);
        }
    }

    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
}
```

And in activity I have this :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopService();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startService();
}

private void stopService(){
    stopService(myIntent);
}

private void startService(){
    myIntent = new Intent(RouteDetailsActivity.this, Sendrer.class);
    startService(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Add log output or something

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think that a while is generate a black screen because all the time is check the list. I remove a while and did a check list diffrence and it works I did this:

```
public class Sendrer extends Service {

    public static boolean running = false;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private SendPhotoTask asyncSender;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        Log.e("tworzenie serwisu ", "tworzenie");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("Dziełanie serwisu ", "Dziełanie");
        if (!MainActivity.photoListSend.isEmpty()) {
            if(!running) {
                asyncSender = new SendPhotoTask();
                asyncSender.execute();
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (running) {
            timer.cancel();
            asyncSender.cancel(true);
            running = false;
        }
        Log.e("service " , "nie działa");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    class SendPhotoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            running = true;
            InputStream responseInputStream = null;
            Log.e("start wysłania " , "start");
            try {
                responseInputStream = HttpConnectionsUtil.sendPhotoRequest(getApplicationContext(), true,  MainActivity.photoListSend.get(0).getName());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("Wysyłanie zdjęcia ", convertStreamToString(responseInputStream));
            return convertStreamToString(responseInputStream);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            MainActivity.photoListSend.remove(0);
            if(!  MainActivity.photoListSend.isEmpty()){
                asyncSender = new SendPhotoTask();
                asyncSender.execute();
                Log.e("Wysyłanie kolejnego " , "zdjecia");
            }
        }
    }

    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
}
```